# Dialog menu not responding to clicks

Tags: c++, winapi

I used the MSVC++ wizard to create a win32 application. I added a new menu resource and added the typical 'File'->'Exit' etc.. Then I added it to the main dialog under the properties in msvc++. When I run the form it shows the menu on the form but if I click on File it doesn't even do the hover and it doesn't show the popup of Exit. Its almost like it's disabled. I really didn't think I needed to add any code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

struct _globals {
    HINSTANCE hInst;
    HWND      hWnd;
} g;

LRESULT CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_     HINSTANCE hInstance,
                      _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                      _In_     LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                      _In_     int       nCmdShow)
{

    InitCommonControls();

    g.hInst = hInstance;

    g.hWnd = CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DialogProc);
    if (g.hWnd == NULL) {
        GetLastError();
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(g.hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(g.hWnd);

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ACCELLS));
    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        if (TranslateAccelerator(g.hWnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
            continue;
        if (IsDialogMessage(g.hWnd, &msg))
            continue;
        // process message
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Typically there is indeed no need to add any code to make popup show. Most likely something is wrong with your resource file (you can post it here actually). It is strange because default win32 application already has working menu with Exit item.

Comment: Why the visual-studio tag?

Comment: @EJoshuaS because I was using the visual studio resource editor to make the menus and was setting it to the dialog using the properties in visual studio.

Comment: The fact that you happen to be writing the program in Visual Studio doesn't make it a question about Visual Studio itself.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I figured since the resource editor and how you add resources to dialogs is specific to how visual studio does it and I was trying to make sure I was doing it correctly. My apologies.:)

Answer (score 0):

Your DialogProc function looks more like a window procedure than a dialog procedure. Unlike window procedures, dalog procedures do not return LRESULT values, they return BOOL values, and they do not call DefWindowProc. There are some other differences as well.

Comment: Thank you! I had it create the default project and started removing stuff to create it dialog based. Although its dialog based now you can still add a window class to it to set the properties with a WNDCLASSEX structure. Which solved my problem.